# Make a link list component of a link component in Vue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I've just made a Link component in Vue, which is new for me. Now I need to make a Link list component, which is basically an UL of LI elements of this Link component. I looked for a solution, but most most of the examples do work with a local array/object and I can't seem to figure it out.

So my question here is: What would a Link list component look like, making use of the existent Link component?

Here's the Link component:

```html
<template>
    <nuxt-link
        :to="localePath(url)"
        :class="$style.link"
    >
        <Icon
            v-if="icon"
            class="icon icon--size:2.5x"
            :name="icon"
        />

        <span
            class="text"
        >
            {{ text }}
        </span>
    </nuxt-link>
</template>

<script src="./index.js"></script>
<style type="text/css" src="./index.module.scss" module lang="scss"></style>
```

```js
import { Icon } from "@/components";

export default {
    props: {
        text: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            default: "",
        },
        url: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            default: "",
        },
        icon: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            default: "",
        },
        expert: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: false,
            default: false,
        },
    },
    components: {
        Icon,
    },
};
```

Should the Link list component receive an array as well like this?

```js
export default {
    props: {
        list: {
            type: Array,
            required: true,
            default: "",
        },
    },
        Link,
    },
};
```

Comment: _"Should the Link list component receive an array as well like this?"_  if you want to pass in the list as a prop, then _yes_. It looks like you're on the right path. Could you please explain what it is you've tried and what is not working?

Comment: @Phil I looked at this article: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Component but I am not sure about the use of the li attributes and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an array of `link` objects that provide the props `text`, `url`, `icon` and optionally `expert` (because I can't see where you're using that), if your goal is to pass this array as a prop to your *Link List* component, then it would look something like this

```html
<template>
  <ul>
    <!-- note the ":key" binding. This should uniquely identify each entry in the list -->
    <li v-for="({ text, url, icon }) in list" :key="url">
      <Link
        :text="text" 
        :url="url" 
        :icon="icon"
      />
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
<script>
import { Link } from '@/components' // or whatever makes sense

export default {
  name: 'LinkList',
  components: { Link },
  props: {
    list: Array
  }
}
</script>
```

---

Using this would look something like

```html
<template>
  <LinkList :list="list" />
</template>
<script>
import { LinkList } from '@/components'

export default {
  components: { LinkList },
  data: () => ({
    list: [{
      text: 'Link #1',
      url: 'https://example.com',
      icon: 'whatever'
    }, {
      // and so on
    }]
  })
}
</script>
```

Comment: Nice! I was making things too complicated. This solves my problem, thanks!